# How to combine prefetch_to_device with make_initializer

Tags: python, tensorflow, prefetch

[Tensorflow 1.8](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/releases/tag/v1.8.0) has introduced `tf.contrib.data.prefetch_to_device`,
which can be used with `tf.data.Dataset.apply`, according to [the official documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/data/prefetch_to_device).

I have written some custom data loading, for which I would like to utilize this to prefetch to GPU. The problem is that this operation needs to be the last one in all transformations of the dataset.
I am using `tf.data.Iterator.make_initializer` and `tf.data.Iterator.from_structure` as follows.
This is a minimal example that raises the error.

```
import tensorflow as tf

class MyData(object):
    def __call__(self):
         return range(100)

expected_shapes = []
expected_types = tf.int32
iterator = tf.data.Iterator.from_structure(output_types=expected_types, output_shapes=expected_shapes)
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(MyData(), output_types=expected_types, output_shapes=expected_shapes)

prefetch_op = tf.contrib.data.prefetch_to_device(device="/gpu:0")
dataset = dataset.apply(prefetch_op)

# This raises NotImplementedError: `prefetch_to_device()` must be the last transformation in a dataset pipeline.
initializer = iterator.make_initializer(dataset)
```

Of course, this does not happen when I turn the order around, but then the prefetching transformation is not taken into account for the initializer.

```
initializer = iterator.make_initializer(dataset)
dataset = dataset.apply(prefetch_op)
```

How can I get this to work to create the initializer after telling it to prefetch? Or is that simply not possible (currently)?
I would like to avoid having to create a new `Iterator`, unlike [this test case from tensorflow](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/commit/4681562607bf4001ecd61492f1e7567be9212c6f).

Comment: Here is a github issue I opened for this, it is being worked on: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/19244